# create hashtags inside the android ediitext

Tags: android, android-edittext, hashtag

I want to display hashtags in the android Edit-text when user types the keyword, and then hits "Space" then Edit-text takes that keyword automatically[image]. here i have attached one screen shot. i need that kind of functionality.User can also remove the hashtag individually and all the hashtags by clicking cancel button.

Need functionality exactly same like when we entering the tags in the stackoverflow when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) library - it provides basically the same functionality as you requested.

Comment: Actually i saw all the libraries. This library contains the autocomplete feature and i don't want to use autocomplete feature.Is there a way to disable the autocomplete feature?

Comment: @ParinParikh: Even if you cannot use the library directly, you can use it as the basis for learning how to implement the "chips" in the `EditText`. From there, a `TextWatcher` probably gives you the hook for "convert the preceding text to a chip".

Comment: I know the procedure how can i achieve this kind of thing but i am not able to implement it in real time. I have made the simple demo through which i can add the hashtags in linearlayout programatically.

Comment: I have also made the demo as per this https://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/making-gosmsproevernote-like-edittext/ . but not able to do it in correct way.